# Lost local sticky notes after signing in to my Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

I have googled this and there are questions about restoring **deleted** notes from the 'snt' file but my situation is slightly different...

My sticky notes was exhibiting the bug whereby I couldn't type into the note (but I could paste text)  I googled this and was instructed to reset the app.  Reset worked, but when I opened sticky notes again my notes were gone.  I signed into my Microsoft account (without really thinking about it) and it restored some sticky notes from a different computer.    So it looks like the sticky notes I had were a local copy (not synced)

Is there any way to get them back?  The 'snt' file on this computer is very old (2016) and doesn't contain the notes I had.

My OS version is 2004 (19041.867) and my sticky notes is 3.8.8.0

Comment: In your Microsoft Account, look in c:\users\you\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb....\LocalState for your notes .  Are they a current date?  Do they contain your notes?  If not, I don't think they are recoverable.

Comment: @John :(  Thanks, I found those files, but on searching their contents I can only find the notes that replaced the notes I wanted, so I guess they're gone.   May not have lost anything important, but the trouble is I can't remember :(